# Formatting Drupal Views RSS feed for chrome

Tags: drupal, rss, drupal-views

Can someone please help me out. I'm looking for a way to force chrome to display my rss feed in a more user friendly way. I know chrome doesnt support this by default but I've seen websites like BBC (http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/shared/bsp/xsl/rss/nolsol.xsl) doing it.

I'm using drupal 7 views to generate the rss feed so anything I do will need to be done by modifying the views-view-rss.tpl.php file which looks as follows:

```
<?php print "<?xml"; ?> version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" <?php print "?>"; ?>
<rss version="2.0" xml:base="<?php print $link; ?>"<?php print $namespaces; ?>>
<channel>
<title><?php print $title; ?></title>
<link><?php print $link; ?></link>
<description><?php print $description; ?></description>
<language><?php print $langcode; ?></language>
<?php print $channel_elements; ?>
<?php print $items; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `view-source:` prefix, will work for every feed.

For example, if your feed has url `http://feeds.guardian.co.uk/theguardian/rss`, you can type `view-source:http://feeds.guardian.co.uk/theguardian/rss` in your Chrome's address bar, and it will display you its full XML.

Also, when viewing a formatted feed (after clicking on RSS icon/link on a page), there is a "Feed" link in the top right corner (on the "Feed preview" blue bar) which takes you to exactly the same `view-source:` page.

Comment: I tried using this method but it outputs the same formatting, just with the line numbers added on the left.

Here's the feed link I'm working with: http://www.acceleration.biz/blog/feed

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use XSL, which requires a minor change to this views template... and a lot of XSL.

```
<?php print "<?xml"; ?> version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" <?php print "?>"; ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/css/rss20.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<rss version="2.0" xml:base="<?php print $link; ?>"<?php print $namespaces; ?>>
```

I find XSL to be obnoxious, but you can probably just based yours off of something you find on the web. Your BBC link is a good start, or NY Times has a fine one too: view-source:http://feeds.nytimes.com/css/rss20.xsl